# What do these arrows mean in inorganic chemistry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

[image]

I tried looking for these arrows in the 3rd molecule starting from the left(Pd) online and in my notes but I couldn't find anything. Is Pd actually bonded to something?

Comment: Aha! So the request for context was even _more_ justified than usual, for it shed a whole new light on the entire picture. Now let me hazard a guess: this is a Pd atom surrounded by two **allyl** ligands, drawn by a chemist whose frivolous use of notation got them banished from the profession and severely beaten by fellow chemists on more than one occasion.

Comment: That is presumably an attempt to represent an allyl anion, which exists as a resonant structure. The double bonds are actually a delocalized double bond. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allylpalladium_chloride_dimer

Comment: Is this not typical use of notation in inorganic chemistry?

Comment: This is a typical representation of a delocalized system when dealing with organic systems. In fact, it is in complete analogy to the structure immediately two the left. The curves associated with an allyl system are just the circles for the cyclopentadienyl system.

Comment: I object; it is not typical even then. You don't draw delocalized systems with double bonds all around.

Answer (score 12):

1. These are not arrows, but fragments of the molecule.
2. We *suspect* they are supposed to mean the [allyl ligands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition-metal_allyl_complex).
3. This hardly qualifies as inorganic chemistry. **Organometallic** is probably the right word to use.
4. The notation is by no means standard; I would go as far as to call it wrong, and not just a slightly-raised-eyebrow kind of wrong, but a punch-in-the-face kind. Those who want to be understood would draw the same molecule in any of the following shapes:
   [image: Pd(allyl)2]

(There are more possible variants.)

So it goes.

Comment: In deed, they are sandwiched metal complexes of allyl compounds. For example, looks [here](https://doi.org/10.1021/om4002632).